# Geometry using complex e powers

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

The question is to expresss $\cos(4\theta)$ and $\sin(4\theta)$ in terms of $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$. This in itself is not that hard using geometrical rules. But my problem is that you need to do it using eulers formula: $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$

Comment: Hint: $(e^{i\theta})^4 = e^{4i\theta}$, and can you rewrite both sides?

Answer (score 2):

Complex numbers work like ordinary algebra, except that $i$ is not a numeric, even though $i^2$ is.

So you expand eg $(c+is)^4 = c^4 + 4c^3 is - 6c^2 s^2 - 4cs^3 i + s^4$.

You then divide it into C+iS, as $C+iS = (c^4-6c^2 s^2 + s^4) + 4i(c^3s - cs^3)$.

You have then that $C = \cos(4\theta)$, and $c=\cos(\theta)$.

Euler's formula is not that hard to figure out, purely on a geometric process, although it does not show you that angles are measured in radians, or that the log base is $e^i$.  What it does show, is that $\cos(a+b)+i\sin(a+b) = (\cos(a)+i\sin(a))(\cos(b)+i\sin(b))$, then $i^2=-1$.

[image]

Create a triangle OAB, so that OA, AB, and AB are Cs, Cc, Cr times the C of the second triangle.  Now continue AB vertically to C, so that a new triangle BCD is similar to OAB. and that BC, BD, CD are in the sizes Sc, Ss and Sr.  The triangle ABD is similar to the second operator, its proportion stands at Cr, Sr, and Rr.

One calculates the coordinate of the point D, as x=OA-CD, and y=AB+BC.  Since we have expressions for these, D = cC-sS, and y=cS+sC, and this is a product of the form (c+is) (C+iS) gives $i^2=-1$.  So it's directly provable from geometry that rotation and resizing maps directly onto complex multiplication.

It does not tell you that the root of this multiplication is $s^{2\pi i}$, but you can definitely see that $\operatorname{cis}(a) \cdot \operatorname{cis}b = \operatorname{cis}(a+b)$, which suffices to solve this problem.

see eg http://www.os2fan2.com/image/complex1.jpg which shows this graphically.  Lengths are given as if were inches, and angles as if were degrees.

Comment: Yes, thanks:  but it's fixed now.